# Get applicable interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, activator

I'm trying to find a good design to a thing I'm working on. As an example, consider a *TextProcessor* class that accepts a string parameter and returns back a processed string.

Now in my implementation there are a number of different *TextProcessors*, each capable handling their own defined set of strings. There are two notable methods in each processor:

```
bool CanProcess(string text);
```

and

```
string Process(string text);
```

In reality these can be marked as **static** but for the sake of implementing a common interface I'm not setting them as static.

In addition to these *TextProcessors* there is a static *TextProcessorFinder* class. As the name implies, it finds the best *TextProcessor* and processes the input.

```
public static class TextProcessorFinder
{
    private static List<ITextProcessor> _processors;

    static TextProcessorFinder()
    {
        _processors = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ITextProcessor))
            && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)
            .Select(t => (ITextProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
            .Where(t => t.IsActive)
            .ToList();
    }

    public static ITextProcessor GetTextProcessor(string text)
    {
        return _processors.Where(p => p.CanProcess(text))
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Priority)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

What I hate about this approach is that I have to create an instance of every known TextProcessor just to call their *CanProcess* function.

I have tried creating an attribute with a simple Func to emulate the *CanProcess* function:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TextProcessorAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Func<string, bool> func;

    public TextProcessorAttribute(Func<string, bool> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }
}

public interface ITextProcessor
{
    bool IsActive { get; }

    int Priority { get; }

    bool CanProcess(string text);

    string Process(string text);
}

// Hard-coded to true
[TextProcessor((s) => { return true; })]
public class SampleTextProcessor : ITextProcessor
{
    // Implement ITextProcessor
}
```

Sadly however, Func is not a valid attribute parameter type.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, creating those instances is the best way to go. There really is no reason to not do it. Instances are cheap and creating them is cheap as well if you are not doing any work in the constructors - which you shouldn't do anyway.

Comment: I guess this works.. They really are cheap however something about creating a bunch of instances for methods that could be static (except for interface implementation) makes me cringe.

Comment: @ZuiqPazu: It doesn't need to make you cringe, it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the `CanProcess` method you ask to each derived ITextProcessor if he can process the text. This is OK in my opinion.
Maybe there are some sort of specialization in the implementations of ITextProcessor, in this case you can create more specific interfaces, ITextTypeAProcessor, ITextTypeBProcessor, etc. Then you can filter by interface in your `GetTextProcessor` method.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. However at the moment I don't have any further specificities upon which to filter.